# How to reduce Netbeans' memory usage?

Tags: php, netbeans, memory-management

When using netbeans to edit a PHP project, the IDE can (over time) use 400+ MB of memory. Is there any way to turn off certain features or other tricks to reduce its memory usage?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't found any way to reduce either Eclipse and Netbeans. The problem is that javas JVM is using significant amout of memory to hold the compiled class representation. For example code is first compiled with something like -O0 for C compilers and later compiled with much better optimization if this is a frequently executed hotspot.

Thats why it is increasing over time. I don't know about any memory leak in Netbeans - so i guess it is just the program code and not the data set which is growing.

The way to reduce it is to remove unnecessary plugins.
But is this with the current prices for 4/8GB of RAM really a problem?

Comment: With only 2 GB of memory it is a problem now, although I am getting some new RAM soon :).

But this can actually still be a problem when running many other memory hogs at the same time (Virtual PC, Firefox, etc)...

Comment: I'm debating upgrading from 2 GB as well, Justin, but like you I run all of those other memory intensive apps so... ugh. My debate, by the way, is between getting the RAM or just getting a more powerful machine (though at only 2 years old I'm having a hard time justifying such an expenditure).

Comment: I thought I was going to upgrade my RAM from 2 to 4GB as well, but after seeing the videos of changing RAM for the MacMini I am not so sure... why you gotta do me like that Apple?

Comment: What about Netbeans for interpreted languages like PHP? Still uses 500MB+ of RAM, and it sure doesn't compile anything.

Comment: @EduardLuca Actually, it does have to load a representation of each of PHP's functions and SPL classes for autocompletion. Those classes and functions are not packaged/namespaced, so it can't really do that incrementally as it may when editing Java. Plus weak-typed framework method/field/constant guessing (in Java it doesn't need to guess), etcetera. Toss in HTML/JavaScript edition and you got yourself quite a burden.

Comment: I make a program which interacts with game. The game already consumes a lot of memory, if you add Firefox, netbeans and OS I'm hitting the top, which is 4GB in my case. So yeah, it's a problem. I disabled all the plugins I could, but many plugins are actually core functions and must remain enabled.