# Disable Netbeans exception report window

Tags: netbeans

I need to disable the "Exceptions" window that pops when you encounter an IDE error in Netbeans - I always report when I can but is driving me crazy right now.

Don't get me wrong, I love the application, but I'm getting tired of the errors on my screen, sometimes needing to delete a file and create him again to enable me to continue.

I can drag it to the side but my mouse loses focus.

I'm using Windows 7 and latest version of Java (netbeans PHP ide)

Is this possible?

Comment: why i get a downvote and a offtopic report to close..this is related to the IDE configuration, just like people ask how to limit memory usage on the ide.. I.E.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557883/how-to-reduce-netbeans-memory-usage

Comment: i hate people downvoting you WITHOUT a comment. not helpful to improve the community.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to modify `<netbeans-install-dir>/etc/netbeans.conf`

Add

```
-J-Dnetbeans.exception.alert.min.level=99999 -J-Dnetbeans.exception.report.min.level=99999
```

to the `netbeans_default_options` entry.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set some properties when launching Netbeans. Modify your application configuration in "nbproject/platform.properties" by finding a line `run.args.extra=...` and adding at the end:

```
-J-Dnetbeans.exception.alert.min.level=99999 -J-Dnetbeans.exception.report.min.level=99999
```

You'll find the details in [Netbeans' wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqUnexpectedExceptionDialog).

Comment: i can only find "project.properties", i tried but it didnt worked..im using netbeans php ide

Comment: thanks but you need to put this information in the config, theres no such file in my php ide, so i accepted christian's anwswer but thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `-J-Dnetbeans.exception.report.min.level=99999` but not the other one. This means the error icon will still appear when there is a problem, and you can report the error if you have a moment, but no dialog will pop up without your asking it to.